# format data from yyyy.mm.dd to Mmm-yy in kdb q

Tags: date, format, kdb

I have a table with dates: ([] date: 2023.09.09 2024.07.01 2027.02.06) and will need to convert it into format "Mmm-yy"

| date |
| --- |
| Sept-23 |
| Jul-24 |
| Feb-27 |

Comment: If one of the answers below has solved your query then please consider marking it as solved to help future viewers of this question.

Answer (score 5):

Same idea as @scottstein37's answer, but with some simplifications:

```
q)d:([] date: 2023.09.09 2024.07.01 2027.02.06)
q)m:("";"Jan";"Feb";"Mar";"Apr";"May";"Jun";"Jul";"Aug";"Sep";"Oct";"Nov";"Dec")
q)update date:"-"sv'flip(m`mm$date;string(`year$date)mod 100)from dates
date
--------
"Sep-23"
"Jul-24"
"Feb-27"
```

Uses the built in modulo key word: https://code.kx.com/q/ref/mod/

and a shortcut to getting the numeric month number: https://code.kx.com/q/ref/cast/#temporal

Comment: nice! mod and `mm$ definitely make more sense :)

Answer (score 2):

```
q)dates: ([] date: 2023.09.09 2024.07.01 2027.02.06)
q)mn: ("Jan";"Feb";"Mar";"Apr";"May";"Jun";"Jul";"Aug";"Sep";"Oct";"Nov";"Dec")
q)update Result:{x,"-",y}'[MonthName; TwoDigitYear] from update TwoDigitYear:string {x-100*floor x%100} `year$date,  MonthName:mn mod[;12] `int$`month$date from dates
date       TwoDigitYear MonthName Result
------------------------------------------
2023.09.09 "23"         "Sep"     "Sep-23"
2024.07.01 "24"         "Jul"     "Jul-24"
2027.02.06 "27"         "Feb"     "Feb-27"
```